# UITableview automatically reloads inside a UITabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, realm

I have a `uitabbarcontroller` and inside a tab I have a `UIViewcontroller` with a `uitableview`. The problem is when I switch to another tab and then switch again to the tab with the `uitableview` it automatically reloads.

Here is my code, I call `fetchAppointments` in my `viewWillappear`:

```
-(void)fetchAppointments:(NSDate *)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate{
    Webservice_2 *web = [[Webservice_2 alloc]init];
    [web fetchAppointmentsWithStart:startDate andEndDate:endDate onCompletion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            [self loadData:_strDate];
            [HUD hide:YES];
        }
    }];

}
-(void)loadData:(NSString *)today{
    NSDate *start = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[today floatValue]];

    NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units fromDate:start];
    components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];


    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [dateComps setDay:[components day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[components month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[components year]];
    [dateComps setHour:0];
    [dateComps setMinute:0];
    [dateComps setSecond:0];
    NSDate *startDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComps];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *offset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offset setDay:1];
    NSDate *endDate =  [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:startDate options:0];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"app_start >= %@ AND app_end <= %@",startDate,endDate];

    appointments = [[Appointment_2 objectsWithPredicate:predicate]sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"app_start" ascending:YES];    NSLog(@"appointments is %@",appointments);

    [tableAppointments reloadData];
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index is out of bounds.'
```

And that is because in my `CellForRowAtIndexPath` I do this:

```
 Appointment_2 *appointment = [appointments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**EXTRA INFO**

- I'm using [Realm](http://realm.io) for storage of my data. and Appointment_2 is a `RLMObject`.
- Also in `fetchAppointmentsWithStart` I delete all of the objects and than add them again.

My question is why does my tableview reloads automatically??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question yourself: Your `UITableView` reloads automatically because you call `fetchAppointments` in `viewWillAppear`, which first causes a reload of the data (with a call to `loadData:`) and subsequently the `UITableView` to reload as well.

Every time you hit an item on in your tab bar, the corresponding view controller's `viewWillAppear` method gets called.

Hope my answer is clear, let me know if you have further questions!

**Update:**
By the way, a quick fix to your crashing issue could be to check whether the  `appointments` array actually contains as much elements as you are trying to obtain from it:

```
Appointment_2 *appointment = nil;
if([appointments count] <= indexPath.row){
  appointment = [appointments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: But loadData is only called when my webservice call is finished? So that cannot trigger the reload.

Comment: yes it does, in `viewWillAppear` you first make a request to the web service and the reload the data! follow the flow in your code and you'll see...

Comment: the web service call is implemented in `fetchAppointments` which you call in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: When i put an NSLog in the first line inside loadData. It does not get printed before the crash ?

Comment: Problem is for some reason solved when I put the code in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillappear